# Sources for the Israelites crossing the Red Sea in a semi circle

Tags: sources-mekorot, yam-suf

What is the source(s) for the Israelites crossing the Red Sea in a semi-circle and thereby ending up on the same side?  I have heard reasons being that they could see the dead Egyptians that way but was looking for a source

Answer (score 3):

The answer is brought by [Tosafos](https://www.sefaria.org/Arakhin.15a.16?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Arakhin.15a.16.1&lang2=bi) on [Masechta Arachin 15a](https://www.sefaria.org/Arakhin.15a.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> כשם שאנו עולין מצד זה (אמרו) כך מצרים עולין מצד אחר - יש לתמוה איך היו ישראל באותו הדור כ"כ מקטני אמנה שסברו שכך יעשה הקב"ה נסים למצרים להעבירם מארצם לא"י **ואומר ר' בשם אביו רבי שמואל שישראל לא עברו הים לרחבו מצד זה לזה שא"כ היו ממהרים ללכת אל א"י אלא רצועה אחת עברו בים לאורך הים עד שפנו למדבר לצד אחד כי לא היו יכולין ללכת מכל צד אם לא יעברו הים ומצרים היו להם מימינם ומשמאלם לפיכך עברו הים רצועה אחת עד שפנו למדבר מצד אחד** וזה כשם שאנו עולין מצד זה ובאנו' למדבר כך מצרים עולין מצד אחר מן המדבר וירדפו אחרינו וישיגו כי סבורים שלא יעברו המצריים בים אלא יבאו מצד אחר ובהכי ניחא הא דכתיב (במדבר לג) ויסעו ממרה וגו' ויחנו על ים סוף ואם עברו רוחב הים עד עבר הים מצד אחר היאך פגעו עוד בים וכי חזרו לאחוריהם אלא ש"מ לאחר שנסעו באורך הים ויצאו כמו כן לאורך הים לדרום מצרים שמצרים כמו כן לרוח דרומית של א"י קרוב לסוף דרומית לצד מערב ונילוס מפסיק בין מצרים ובין א"י והים מצד דרומית של ארץ מצרים ממזרח למערב  ונסעו לחוף הים מצפון הים שהוא דרומית של מצרים **ואח"כ יצאו לאחר שהלכו כחצי גורן עגולה** ויצאו בצד צפוני שלהם שהיא דרומית של ארץ אדום ומזרחית של ארץ מצרים ואח"כ הלכו קצת ימים עד מרה ואח"כ היו עדיין אצל הים וכשהוצרכו ליכנס לא"י לא הוצרכו לעבור הים אלא סיבבו ארץ אדום וארץ מואב שהוא בדרומית של א"י ומזרחית של ארץ מצרים

A summary is as follows:

The Gemara states, "Just as we are ascending from one side, so too perhaps the Egyptians are ascending from the other side, (and we will not be saved)." Tosafos asks how they could react in such a way as even those of lesser faith had experienced a myriad of miracles in Egypt, so how now could they start doubting? Tosafos reasons that it must have been that they didn't traverse the sea along its width, as if so, they would have hurried into Eretz Yisroel. Rather they must have followed a strip of the sea travelling along its length until they were facing the desert to one side, since otherwise they couldn't go on either side if the sea did not pass and the Egyptians had them on their right and on their left. As such, they had to travel along one stretch until they were facing the desert from one side.

Now we can understand why they had a moment of doubt. As they were coming from one side, they thought the Egyptians would inevitably meet them from the other side.

If one analyses their travels - they journeyed from Marah and then camped by the Yam Suf. If they traversed the width of the sea until they passed to the other side how then could they have been hit by the Egyptians, thus we have to conclude that if they travelled along the length they would come out facing southwards of Egypt as Egypt was South of Israel, and to the west of the River Nile which separated Egypt and Israel. The sea would consequently be on the southern side of Egypt heading from east to west, and they travelled along the shore from the north which was south of Egypt. The trajectory was therefore a semi-circle, as they  went out on their north side which is south of the land of Edom and east of the land of Egypt. They subsequently travelled a few days until Marah after which they were still by the sea meaning that when they needed to enter the land of Israel they no longer need to pass the sea but rather encircle the land of Edom and Moav which was in the south of Israel and east of Egypt.

The diagram provided on the daf spells out their trajectory clearer (than I probably did!):
[image]

Comment: See: https://www.torchweb.org/torah_detail.php?id=294  :  "The Tosafists base their position on a passage in the Talmud in Arachin 15a which derives from a verse in Psalms 106:7 that the Jewish people demonstrated little faith after they crossed the dry land in the middle of the Red Sea. They assumed that just as they were saved from drowning in the Red Sea, the Egyptians also survived."