# The Yetziat Mitrazyim Path

Tags: history, yetziat-mitzrayim, yam-suf

I know there are many opinions on Yitziat Mitzraim. The path taken through the sea and how/where they went.

Is there a sefer/website that shows (picture or text) the different shitas? I am hoping for Rishonim but Achronim help, not interested in Archaeologists opinions except where they are trying to understand a Rishon.

I will also accept answers that point to the Psukim by each Rishon that describes their opinion though this might be more laborious. Points to anyone giving me a shita and its source.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/119179/sources-for-the-israelites-crossing-the-red-sea-in-a-semi-circle

Comment: http://www.truthofland.co.il/masaot/journeys_with%20pictures.htm here this goes through the main journeys

Answer (score 1):

Desert Encamptments by Rabbi Alex Hool and Search for Sinai by Rabbi Alexander Hool. He mostly focuses on his shita (based on the Rishonim, midrashim, and psukim) but also discusses the other opinions (including archeologists', which will not interest you.)

https://mosaicapress.com/product/the-desert-encampments/

[https://www.amazon.com/Desert-Encampments-Sinai-Holy-Land/dp/195237037X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/195237037X)

You also may want to check the maps in the back of the varius editions of chumashim such as Oz Vehadar.

Comment: @msj121 There is also a article about the Yam Suf crossing location by the same Rabbi Alexander Hool in the most recent edition of Ami Magizine (Pesach issue on p. 276)